# What's the difference between those 2 queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you explain my why, in Oracle, this query returns something:

```
SELECT discounts.DiscountId,
       discounts.ShortDisplay,
       discounts.Display,
       discounts.Description,
       BillDetails.BillId,
       BillDetails.BillRow,
       BillDetails.BillId  AS BillIdTax,
       BillDetails.BillRow AS BillRowTax,
       BillDetails.FEDERAL_TAX_POSTPAID,
       BillDetails.TOTAL_RATE
FROM   discounts
       INNER JOIN BillDetails
         ON discounts.DiscountId = BillDetails.DiscountId
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN BillDetailsTax
         ON BillDetails.BillId = BillDetailsTax.BillId
            AND BillDetails.BillRow = BillDetailsTax.BillRow
WHERE  BillDetails.BillId = 602237
```

And this one nothing :

```
SELECT discounts.DiscountId,
       discounts.ShortDisplay,
       discounts.Display,
       discounts.Description,
       BillDetails.BillId,
       BillDetails.BillRow,
       BillDetails.BillId  AS BillIdTax,
       BillDetails.BillRow AS BillRowTax,
       BillDetails.FEDERAL_TAX_POSTPAID,
       BillDetails.TOTAL_RATE
FROM   BillDetails,
       BillDetailsTax BillDetails,
       discounts
WHERE  BillDetails.BillRow = BillDetailsTax.BillRow(+)
       AND BillDetails.BillId = BillDetailsTax.BillId(+)
       AND BillDetails.DiscountId = discounts.DiscountId
       AND BillDetails.BillId = 602237
```

Are those 2 queries not similar?

Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a query parsing service.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Oracle non standard outer join syntax. What determines if it is treated as `INNER -> RIGHT` or `RIGHT -> INNER`?

Comment: Closing this question was not justified. It is a very valid question regarding the difference of Oracles join syntax vs ANSI joni syntax.

Comment: @MartinSmith: The column the plus is added to. In the example, the `(+)` is added to `BillDetailsTax.BillRow`, i.e. `BillDetailsTax` is allowed to be missing.

Comment: Actually the second query does seem to contain an error. It has `BillDetailsTax BillDetails ,` but I assume that is supposed to just be `BillDetailsTax,`

Comment: So, essentially, the second query is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `BillDetailsTax` and the first query is a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` on `BillDetailsTax`. I think actually the second query makes more sense and doesn't return anything, because there exists no bill with ID 602237 and a discount.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Indeed. Good catch. Maybe just an error that happened while preparing this question. I don't think that this query would actually execute like this.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, you're right, it's a problem between RIGHT and LEFT. I must translate that query to TSQL. So It's a LEFT and not a RIGHT. But why is this question closed???

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it was incorrectly closed. Most likely those people didn't read the question properly.

Comment: And do you know how to re-open it, @DanielHilgarth? I'm a newbie here! :)

Comment: I voted for it to be re-opened and so did three others. However, for it to be re-opened, we need 5 votes from users with enough reputation but currently only have 4. I additionally flagged it for moderator attention. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Oh, hey :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column the plus is added to is the "outer" side. In your second query, the (+) is added to BillDetailsTax.BillRow. That means that the value from the `BillDetailsTax` is allowed to be missing.

So, essentially, the second query is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `BillDetailsTax` and the first query is a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` on `BillDetailsTax`.

I think actually the second query makes more sense. It doesn't return anything, because there exists no bill with ID 602237 and a discount.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, strange syntax for me! :)

Comment: @user1986841: Not just for you ;-) It actually is a very old syntax that isn't really used anymore. It has been created by Oracle before the so-called ANSI Join syntax (that's what we are using today) had been defined.